# Cluster creation in openlayer 6.4.3 - Uncaught TypeError: this.source.loadFeatures is not a function

Tags: cluster-analysis, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

I am trying to create cluster using ol 6.4.3. My script is

```
var cluster_data = {
            "type": "Feature",
          'features': [
            {
              'type': 'Feature',
              'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [686213.47091037, 1093486.3776117],
              },
            },
            {
              'type': 'Feature',
              'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [687067.04391223, 1094462.7275206],
              },
            },
            {
              'type': 'Feature',
              'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [687214.60645801, 1094362.868384],
              },
            }

            ],
        };
var features = new Array(3);
 var source = new ol.layer.Vector({
          features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(cluster_data),
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 40,
  source: source,
});

var styleCache = {};
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: function (feature) {
    var size = feature.get('features').length;
    var style = styleCache[size];
    if (!style) {
      style = new Style({
        image: new CircleStyle({
          radius: 10,
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
          }),
          fill: new Fill({
            color: '#3399CC',
          }),
        }),
        text: new Text({
          text: size.toString(),
          fill: new Fill({
            color: '#fff',
          }),
        }),
      });
      styleCache[size] = style;
    }
    return style;
  },
});
map.addLayer(clusters);
```

I have added other 3 Tile layers **map.getLayers().extend([bm,road,landmark]);** and trying to add cluster over this. But getting error **Uncaught TypeError: this.source.loadFeatures is not a function** while adding cluster.

The map I got after adding my layer is
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because

```
var source = new ol.layer.Vector({
```

should be

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
```

Also the first type in the data before the features should be

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
```

And if you are using the OpenLayers full build
`new Style` `new CircleStyle` `new Stroke` `new Fill` and `new Text`
should be
`new ol.style.Style` `new ol.style.Circle` `new ol.style.Stroke` `new ol.style.Fill` and `new ol.style.Text`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.1/proj4.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>

proj4.defs("EPSG:32643","+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var cluster_data = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          'features': [
            {
              'type': 'Feature',
              'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [686213.47091037, 1093486.3776117],
              },
            },
            {
              'type': 'Feature',
              'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [687067.04391223, 1094462.7275206],
              },
            },
            {
              'type': 'Feature',
              'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [687214.60645801, 1094362.868384],
              },
            }

            ],
        };

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
          features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(cluster_data),
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 40,
  source: source,
});

var styleCache = {};
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: function (feature) {
    var size = feature.get('features').length;
    var style = styleCache[size];
    if (!style) {
      style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 10,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#3399CC',
          }),
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: size.toString(),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#fff',
          }),
        }),
      });
      styleCache[size] = style;
    }
    return style;
  },
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:32643"
  })
});

map.addLayer(clusters);

map.getView().fit(source.getExtent());
map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom() - 6);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanku..It worked..but one problem, cluster is displaying at the center of the map, not in actuall geometric position

Comment: What projection are you using? In web mercator your coordinates are near Minna in Nigeria.

Comment: we are using utm 43N

Comment: The cluster seems to be correctly positioned when the view is defined as UTM 43N.  I have added some working code to the answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your running code. When I add my layer to your answer, the map is projecting in wrong position. I have generated map using Mapproxy1.12, Mapnik3.0. I will add the current map image in my question

Comment: I have experienced the same problem... map rendering is not correct. OSM and google map working fine but map rendering  from gis  data is not getting correctly

Comment: If you use a tile layer which is not EPSG:3857 you must set the projection and tile grid in the source options.

Comment: yes..I am using tile layer. I added projection, but tilegrid gives error. Just added extend & tile size only, but resuts in error. ***Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined***. My code is .var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
  extent: [291627,904686,958569,1426831],
  tileSize: [512, 256],
});

Comment: I have added it as another question . please have a look..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774440/how-to-add-tilegrid-to-tile-layer-in-openlayer-6-4-3